# restore GitHub repo after re install windows system

Tags: git, github

i'm new on Github

i have a project work on local, i use GitHub for windows

My question is if try to re install my system, copy all files into different Hard drive.

How can i restore my repo after I re install my system and all software.

Do I must use clone to Git Hub server and clone back after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> copy all files into different Hard drive.

If you do that then  not, it is sufficient to have `.git` folder and your whole repository is in this folder.

This `.git` folder is hidden under windows, if you do `show hidden files` in windows explorer then you will see it.

You can do simple exercise copy your `.git` folder from your local git repository to another folder and see what happens.
I bet that you will get a lot of changes ing `git status` all deleted files but if you checkout branch it will all be back without cloning from server.

Comment: where can i find this folder?

Comment: In your git repository on local hard drive, where you have your project. To show hidden files check this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7

Comment: 1 more question, when i create a repo,  i got 2 files .gitattributes & .gitignore, can i delete these 2 files?

Comment: Those are quite useful so I would take those as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to clone your repo again. Once you reinstall your OS (obviously, keeping the original repo folder) and apps, you'll only have to [set your git global options again](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup). Your repository settings are saved [in a folder inside the repo root itself](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html), just keep this folder and everything needed will be there, always.